# binding acolumn in mvc telerik grid due to condition

Tags: model-view-controller, binding, grid, telerik

I have a telerik mvc grid with server bindig

I want to bind a column depending on a condition: i did
 columns.Bound(p =>
                                {
                                    if (Helper.Language.StartsWith("en"))
                                    {
                                       p.Patient.FirstNameEnglish;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                     p.Patient.FirstName;
                                    }
                                })

but it gives this error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

if (Helper.Language.StartsWith("en"))
{
   columns.Bound(p => p.Patient.FirstNameEnglish);
}
else
{
   columns.Bound(p => p.Patient.FirstName);
}